# If anyone click anwhere on my site, a new link open in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a WordPress based site with good visitor. I want when anyone click on my site a new link open in a new tab. I am not expert on coding. So, which code i use and where i put it?

Comment: what do you mean by 'anywhere' ?

Comment: @Ratul Sharker mean any space on my site

Answer (score 4):

Find your anchors links into your WP template, should look like this

```
<a href="http://your_url_here.html">Link</a>
```

add `target="_blank"` so it looks like :

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://your_url_here.html">Link</a>
```

Comment: i want a code like that `if (getCookie('c')!=1)
  {
  window.location.href="https://link";
  setCookie('c', 1, 24*60*60*1000);      
  }`  but i do not understand where and how i put this @Jorel Amthor

Comment: @adder69 so add it? This is literally the most basic HTML.

Comment: @adder69 It litterally makes no sense. 
PS: dont click on this link, it redirects to porn.

Comment: But i do not understand where and how i put this

Comment: @ Jorel Amthor  which link ?

Comment: `if (getCookie('c')!=1) { window.open("https://link", '_blank') ; setCookie('c', 1, 24*60*60*1000); },` 

Modify the window.location to window.open, then `("https://link", '_blank') `replace link with your url

Comment: On wordpress theme where i add it, after body tag or after hed tag?

Comment: You replace the code you gaves me with the one i gave you, adding proper url instead of `https://link`.

I cant help your further, if you struggle with copy/paste maybe you shouldnt be involved into website creations or anything related to this. It's okay to admit the limit of your own knowledge, there's plenty of people you could hire at low cost to change your WP theme.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `<a`> tags, you can add `target="_blank"` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In question title he mention **Anywhere**, which derived to following solution

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is the title</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mainWindowLoaded()
        {
            console.log("Main windwo is loaded");
            document.getElementById('wholebody').addEventListener('click', clickedInBody);
        }

        function clickedInBody()
        {
            console.log("log added");
            window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        }
        window.addEventListener('load', mainWindowLoaded);
    </script>
</head>


<body >

    <div
        id='wholebody' 
        style="background-color:rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.3); position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1">

    </div>

    <h1> Your website content goes here  </h1>

</body>
```

The key idea here is to add an overlay div of which `z-index` is higher than the whole page content. a `click` action is added to this div, which silently catch all the click events.

Comment: does it full fill your requirement ? @adder69